# How to copy and paste a cell value to another worksheet in the same workbook

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

Currently I am working on making a macro that needs does the following things.

1) It looks through the top row, returning a named column

2) It then selects this column

3) Then it loops through column looking for the first value greater than zero.

4) I then take the row value of this "first" instance

5) From my public variables, I get a column value (#'s)

6) I combine the row value and column value to find my "data point"

Finally I want copy this value to another worksheet in the same workbook called "Critical Signals"

This is where I'm having trouble. Everytime I run my code I get a error "1004". I can't seem to copy and paste my selected cell to my second worksheet. Any ideas?

```
Sub Locate_Start_Of_Test()
'Use the Find Method to identify signal columns
Dim SigCol As Integer
Dim SigRow As Integer
Dim Cell As Range
Dim CritRow As Integer
'Variables to hold critical point of Start of Test

SigRow = 1 'Row Location of Signal Names

SigCol = Sheet1.Cells(SigRow, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="EngAout_N_Actl (rpm)",     LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
'SigCol now holds the value of rpm column


Columns(SigCol).Select

CritRow = 1

For Each Cell In Selection
    If Cell.Value > 0 And Cell.Value <> "EngAout_N_Actl (rpm)" Then
        Exit For
    End If
    CritRow = CritRow + 1
Next Cell

Sheets(1).Range(Cells(CritRow, Trip_point)).Copy
Sheets("Critical Signals").Activate
Range("E4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, simply remove `Range` from this line:

```
Sheets(1).Range(Cells(CritRow, Trip_point)).Copy
```

So that it looks like this:

```
Sheets(1).Cells(CritRow, Trip_point).Copy
```

---

Also, I'd recommend not using `Active` or `Select` statements.  For example your 4 lines of code to copy and paste could look like this instead:

```
Sheets("Critical Signals").Range("E4") = Sheets(1).Cells(CritRow, Trip_point)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I would upvote you but sadly I need more than 15 rep.